# Introductory abstract algebra, solve $|x − e| = x$ to find whether an identity element exists.

Tags: abstract-algebra, absolute-value

I'm not sure how to solve the equation $$|x − e| = x,$$
where $e$ is the identity element. The book I'm reading gives the following proof of $$x * y = |x − y|$$ not having an identity element, but I don't get how they got to it, i.e. I don't get how to expand the absolute value in this case:

$$x ∗ e = x$$

$$|x − e| = x$$

$$e = 2x$$

Edit: The set is $\mathbb{R}$

Edit2: I'm looking for a step by step expansion of absolute value. I think in the negative case e should be 0, and in the positive it should be 2x, but I'm not sure how i would write it down in an answer.

Comment: What is your set?

Comment: You should specify the set on which the operation is defined. That operation does have an identity element if the set is  $\{0\}$ or $[0, \infty)$ for example.

Comment: It would make sense to take the set $X$ the binary operation $*$ is defined on to be $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$, since the absolute value is then required in order for the formula to yield a binary operation, i.e. to take values in $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$. If this is indeed what is intended, then $e=0$ is an identity element since $0*x=x*0 = x=|x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$. If you take $*$ to define a binary operation on $\mathbb R$, then there is no identity element, since if $x<0$ then for any $e \in \mathbb R$ we have $e*x=|x-e|\geq 0$, so $e*x\neq x$.

Comment: @jjagmath of course, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are doing.

What is your set and what is your group operation?

It looks like you group operation $*$ is:

$x*y = |x-y|$

What is the identity element in the group.

You identified $e = 2x$ as a candidate. But this creates problems. If $2x$ is the identity and $y$ is also in the set then it must be the case that $y*2x = y$.

Futhermore, if $2x$ is the identity then $2x$ must be in the set and $2x*2x = 2x$.

$e = 0$ must be the identity in this problem.

Comment: Edited the question to specify that the set is reals, and you were right about group operation. My problem is expanding the absolute value.

Comment: $e = 0$ doesn't work, as $x * e = \lvert x \rvert \neq x$ for $x < 0$. That's why the book says there is no identity here.

Comment: @zaq So, if this is a group with the group operation above, the set must be non-negative.  Could be non-negative reals, or non-negative integers, or perhaps a subset of either.

Answer (score 0):

What is was looking for is along those lines:
$$x-e>0 \: => |x-e|=x-e \:=> x-e=x, e=0$$

$$x-e<0 \:=> |x-e|=-(x-e) \:=> -x+e=x, e=2x$$

$0 \neq 2x$, hence there is no identity element.

Is that valid?